# Does KPL support proxy configurations?

Tags: amazon-kinesis-kpl

I have Spring beans configured in a microservice as follows that I'm using to connect to Kinesis:

```
@Bean
// ClientConfiguration has proxy protocol, proxy host, and proxy port set
public AmazonKinesisAsync amazonKinesisAsync(ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration, AppProperties properties) {
  return AmazonKinesisAsyncClientBuilder.standard().
    withClientConfiguration(clientConfiguration).withRegion(properties.getRegion()).build();
}

@Bean
public KinesisProducerConfiguration kinesisProducerConfiguration(AppProperties properties) {
  return new KinesisProducerConfiguration()
    .setRegion(properties.getRegion());
}
```

[This GH issue](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-producer/issues/186#issuecomment-368983564) states that the KPL doesn't support proxy configuration, but I'm hoping there is a way to utilize KPL behind a firewall. So, my main question is whether or not KPL supports proxy configuration, and if not, how can I use KPL/KCL behind a corporate firewall? I've read about AWS Kinesis VPC Endpoints [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/vpc.html), so would this be the only alternative we would have if we can't use KPL with a proxy configuration?